# How To Save CommonMark In MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, serialization, commonmark

I'd like to support saving CommonMark data in my node application.  I've never dealt with saving Markdown or CommonMark to a Mongo database before.  Should I save CommonMark data as a simple string in Mongo or is there a more optimal way to store it?

```
// Post Schema
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. And I assume you use Mongoose?

Comment: Yes, it's a text format and therefor it's stored as a string in Mongo.